# I want apache give no response

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am running apache2.2 on my WinXP PC.
I want no body but a specified IP access the site.
I already use httpd.conf to deny other request.
But that's not enough, I now want to set apache to send no response, not 403.
To be simple, I want to hide my server, I don't want others know I am running a webserver.

Comment: So install/configure a firewall. Off topic for SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is clearly something very easy to do with a firewall, so you should try to install and configure a firewall.

On the apache side the only thing you could try is using **mod_security** with the "**drop**" action. Check [this servfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/401592/65727) for example. But if the connection is closed by apache an attacker could still see the connection was first accepted, so your web server is not really hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the Apache server to localhost only.  I've not tested it, but in ports.conf, you could change:

```
Listen 80
```

to

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

That would make apache bind to the IP address 127.0.0.1, which is only available from the machine itself.